# How to enable customer account in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento2.2.7

I am not able to log in to Magento 2 frontend.

> **"You did not sign in correctly or your account is temporarily disabled."**

This message is showing after the correct login.
How to solve this error?

Comment: Did you resolve your issue?

Comment: yes email id was wrong and i just reset the email id from back end

Comment: That's great, please mark answer correct if it is helpful to you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be for multiple reasons, either your account has different group, or it is deleted, or password missmatch, or email address is incorrect.

Magento uses same error message for all the above issues.

To fix this, go to

> Customers -> All customers
>   Edit your account user.

1. Verify if email address is correct
2. Use "Reset Password" to change your password.
3. Check if user group is "General"